# LESS add class with pseudo selector

Tags: css, less

I use LESS and here is my example:

```
.arrow{
   color: red;
}
.arrow:before{
   content: ">";
}

.button{
  background: blue;
  .arrow;
  &:before{
    border: 1px solid;
  }
}
```

And this is CSS after parsing:

```
.button{
   background: blue;
   color: red;
}
.button:before{
   border: 1px solid; // HERE IS NO  content: ">" !!!
}
```

How to add `:before` pseudo-element from `.arrow` class to my button?

Comment: Why not use `extend`?

Comment: As already mentioned in the answers below you can use [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature), but to comment the problem of your snippet: if you want to use `.arrow` as a mixin and need `.arrow:before` styles to be a part of this mixin you have to nest `.arrow:before` styles in (any) `.arrow {...}` definition... (i.e. `.arrow` can work as a mixin but `.arrow:before` can't).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `extend` option like below. It basically applies all properties of the `arrow` class to the `button` class also. The `all` keyword means the child classes are also extended.

**LESS:**

```
.button{
    background: blue;
    &:extend(.arrow all);
    &:before{
        border: 1px solid;
    }
}
```

**Compiled CSS:**

```
.arrow,
.button {
    color: red;
}
.arrow:before,
.button:before {
    content: ">";
}
```

Comment: @Sergey Kudryashov, just in case, there's dark side of the `extend all` you need to keep in mind though: if somewhere in your code you will have another `.arrow` style this style will apply to your `.button` too (e.g. `#foo .bar.baz + div > p:hover.array {color: red}` will set the red color to your button as well).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I guess you meant arrow instead of array in your example, right?

Comment: @DaviLima yes, it was a typo.

Answer (score 5):

I think the Extend feature ought to do the trick:

```
.button { 
    &:extend(.arrow all);

    background: blue;
    &:before {
        border: 1px solid;
    }
}
```

See http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature